# How to create List collection with different SOQLs in APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an APEX trigger which trigers after insert. It is suppose to select opportunities via SOQL and assign it to List collection.
But List and SOQL depends on another variable Vehicle_Type__c. Below code is not working, I get error "PulledOpportunities" variable does not exist.

```
if ( l.Vehicle_Type__c != 'Truck' ) {


List<Opportunity> PulledOpportunities = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =: 'Active' AND Med_Expiration__c >=: System.TODAY() AND Opp_Record_Type_ID__c =: 'ABC' AND WareHouse__c IN: WarehouseList];

} else {


List<Opportunity> PulledOpportunities = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =: 'Active' AND Opp_Record_Type_ID__c =: 'ABC' AND WareHouse__c IN: WarehouseList];

}

Integer FoundOpportunities = PulledOpportunities.size();
```

Any suggestion how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable `PulledOpportunities` outside the `if`/`else` construct. Your variables are scoped to their nearest enclosing block (curly braces) so they go out of scope when then `if` ends.

```
List<Opportunity> PulledOpportunities;

if ( l.Vehicle_Type__c != 'Truck' ) {
    PulledOpportunities = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Active' AND Med_Expiration__c >=: System.TODAY() AND Opp_Record_Type_ID__c = 'ABC' AND WareHouse__c IN: WarehouseList];
} else {
    PulledOpportunities = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Active' AND Opp_Record_Type_ID__c = 'ABC' AND WareHouse__c IN: WarehouseList];
}

Integer FoundOpportunities = PulledOpportunities.size();
```

Note also that you should only be using the `:` bind operator where you are comparing to an Apex variable. Static values like `'Active'` do not require, and should not use, bind notation.